# Cannot find reference in '__init__.py while using zeromq

Tags: python, sockets, pycharm, anaconda, zeromq

I want to try this simple example but I get the error:

> Cannot find reference 'REP' in '**init**.py

I use python 3.7/miniconda/pycharm

Any idea?

```
 import time
 import zmq

 context = zmq.Context()
 socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
 socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

 while True:
     #  Wait for next request from client
     message = socket.recv()
     print("Received request: %s" % message)

     #  Do some 'work'
     time.sleep(1)

     #  Send reply back to client
     socket.send(b"World")
```

Comment: It would be helpful for us if you could edit your question and include the full error traceback.

Comment: Thank you. It is highlighted if I move the cursor to the zmq.REP. If I wannt to import like : "from zmq import REP" don't found it.